# How to deploy file to artifactory without changing its name?

Tags: build.gradle

I'm trying to deploy "20170928-WSName.zip" to artifactory using gradle. And as the result I have file named "20170928-WSName-.zip". The version is added automaticly. How to deploy file whithout chanding the name of the file? Maybe there is another (non-maven?) plugin for this purpose?

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'                                   

ext {
    WSName = 'WSName'
    ArchiveName = '20170928-WSName'
    Dir = 'directory'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://...'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.7' 
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives file:file(ArchiveName + '.zip'), name:ArchiveName, type:'zip'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
    }
}

artifactory {
    archivesBaseName = WSName
    version = ''
    group = Dir

    publish {
        contextUrl = 'http://...'
        repository {
            repoKey = 'repokey'
            username = 'user_name'
            password = 'pass'
        }
        defaults {
            //publications('maven')
            publishConfigs('archives') 
            publishBuildInfo = false
            publishArtifacts = false
            publishPom = false
            publishIvy = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In maven this is achievable using the tag `<finalName>` under the `<build>` tag as :

```
<build>
    <finalName>20170928-WSName</finalName>
    ....
</build>
```

---

The [`archiveName`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName) looks like a similar attribute in gradle to be [used as](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-set-an-explicit-archive-name-when-doing-uploadarchives/6775/3) :-

```
jar.archiveName = "20170928-WSName.zip"
```

Comment: I'm trying to deploy zip file, not jar.

Comment: @ОльгаЖук The extension can be specified accordingly as per the link I've shared. updated in the answer.